# Got "INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER" when called usersApi.createSignatures with SDK 3.6.0

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I integrated the 3.6.0 SDK of docusign and tried to call it to create a new signature.

but got this error:
:{"errorCode":"INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER","message":"The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Invalid imageType: signature_image"}

[Code Screenshot details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PT6yB.png) 
I set the imageType = "signature_image" according to the document, [Docusgin document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRD46.png)

but an error was returned. Is the problem with the version of the SDK?
:{"errorCode":"INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER","message":"The request contained at least one invalid parameter. Invalid imageType: signature_image"}

Then i tried :
[update code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqNXm.png)

it success, but there is no img that i upload, but wrong signature with file name :
[Result in docusign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghrsh.png)

Thank you for any helpful suggestions and methods, thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to update the signature or the initials image?

Comment: yes , i'm trying to create a new signature and upload to docusign. with java sdk 3.6.0 function : "usersApi.createSignatures "@InbarGazit  thanks for your help.

Comment: but in your code I also see "initials" ?

Comment: Hello again Yurui, just checking if you can update this, is there an Initial or Signature update? does it give you an error? does it not work?